# Change location of error_log for userdir + suphp

Tags: apache-2.2, php, suphp, fcgi

I have needed to duplicate a *FastCGI* + *suPHP*, and I have re-created the setup but unlike the CentOS one my `error_log` files are all in `/log/apache/` instead of the directories where the script triggered the error. **How do I configure PHP to write all `error_log`s to `~/error_log`?**

Comment: For clarity: this is suphp and mod_userdir integration, so that for any given user, when using suphp to run a script on their behalf, the error_log goes into a per-user error_log file. [deleted my non-answer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your suphp configuration file is possibly missing a logfile statement which states where logging information is stored. Based on their documentation this should be configurable with variable definitions. Further info should be found here : http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=CONFIG

Comment: There is only one setting that isn't relative, how would it write logs to different places?